# not receiving emails from php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I know I'm being sent a status of '1' from this process file as my JavaScript resulting is functioning. Problem is that I'm not getting the email.

```
<?php
//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$comment = ($_GET['comment']) ?$_GET['comment'] : $_POST['comment'];
//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;
//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, 
//you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$comment) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your comment.'; 
//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {
    //recipient - change this to your name and email
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';    
    //sender
    $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = 'Comment from ' . $name;    
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Comment</td><td>' . nl2br($comment) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';
    //send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

    //if POST was used, display the message straight away
    if ($_POST) {
        if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

    //else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
    //ajax script can react accordingly
    //1 means success, 0 means failed
    } else {
        echo $result;    
    }
//if the errors array has values
} else {
    //display the errors message
    for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
    echo '<a href="form.php">Back</a>';
    exit;
}
//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: take out everything but the most basic mail() parts, hard code them, send to at 5 differently hosted address, check the mail log.

Comment: Is this a Linux machine or a Windows machine that PHP is running on?  Without some more information it is hard to provide you with a direction.

Comment: xampp apache. sorry, forgot to mention that

Comment: xampp does not typically install a mail server. have you installed one?

Comment: also doesn't work on godaddy which i believe is linux

Comment: You could be blocked by spam filters - try adding `"-f your-email@example.com"` after the `$headers` - so `... $headers, "-f your-email@example.com");` This will make sure that the email is sent from you and not the apache server (or at least mask it that way). Ultimately, I would suggest using something like PHPMailer instead of the basic `mail()` function

Comment: its not related to ur code bt this tool will help u to check ur Email preivew in ur localhost http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned you are using GoDaddy.  GoDaddy requires you set the sender address legitimately to match the domain of the site it is sending from or use SMTP with Authentication.

**There is a huge gaping hole with this method of sending email.  Spammers can easily override the *From:* header by inserting additional recipients.**

I'm not sure how mail centric your application plans to be, but I would recommend using a package like **PHPMailer** or **PEAR::Mail** as it takes care of email handling for you at a much higher level.  This let's you focus on more important parts of your application.  The built-in PHP `mail()` feature is very limited in its abilities and as you try to extend your mail capabilities you'll run into many road blocks that the base `mail()` function just cannot handle without a lot of additional logic on your behalf (attachments, MIME-types, etc come to mind).

Comment: Someone's going to downvote my answer but not give a reason why? Well that's helpful.

Comment: I give +1 because you answered the question in your second paragraph. The -1 most likely came from the slap in the first paragraph, then the solicitation of a library in the third. Answer the question first, then show a potentially better solution.

Comment: Yes but it's an important slap to make.  Spammers thrive on web forms with holes like these and I'm just trying to mitigate the disaster from occurring.  Hence why I also suggested the library as it implements email correctly, above all else.

Comment: I reorganized the paragraphs.  Hopefully that presents a better solution.

Comment: I plan on using a hidden blank input and validate for spammers

Comment: You didn't fix my problem. I don't want to take a different route!

Comment: Did you read my first paragraph?  You can't send messages that aren't from the domain you're sending them from.  i.e.: `$from` cannot be anything other than `some-email-name@yourdomainname.com`, where the first part can be whatever, but the domain must be the name of the domain you're hosting this script on.

Answer (score 0):

when testing mails you can test it directly to your server, php mail has a function that already runs on it. if you test it on xampp locally it will not send , unless you have set the php mailer in localhost. but for me its better to test it on server than in localhost.